# perl Net::Telnet basics

Tags: perl, buffer, telnet

As mentioned in the [cpan documentation of Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.03/lib/Net/Telnet.pm):

**All output is flushed while all input is buffered. Each object contains its own input buffer.**

Talking crudely, is it so that the command that I am sending is referred to as the *output* and the result as *input* as it is buffered?

I have the following code for sending commands and receiving the results.

```
sub sendCmd {
my $t = shift @_;
my $query = shift @_;
$t->buffer_empty;
print "Sending command $query to telnet target\n";
@out = $t->cmd(String => $query,Timeout => 70,
            Errmode => 'return',Prompt => '/#/');
push(@out, ${$t->buffer});
$t->buffer_empty;
return @out;
}
```

The problem here is that if I have a loop of the following kind:

```
while(1)
{
    @res1 = sendCmd('cmd1');
    print @res1,"\n";
    @res2 = sendCmd('cmd2');
    print @res2,"\n";
}
```

This gives the expected alternating output for some time but after that :

**problem 1**:i observe after a while that - the result of cmd1 appears as the result for cmd2 and vice versa.

**problem 2**: the command may itself appear appended to the result.

Please help me with both these problems. Meanwhile I was thinking to revert to waitfor - print combination.

Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose without details.  Could your "prompt" be appearing somewhere in the command output or a command timing out?  If so, output will get attached to the next command and will thereafter be one behind.